# How to visualize business processes using Microsoft Visio

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2003

How can I visualize business processes of a company using Microsoft Visio? I means processes like printing a form, fill in the form, enter the form data into a system and so on.

**UPDATE:** Maybe I should say "work processes". I mean a diagram readable by end-users. So for filling in a form I can use "Document" (Basic Flowchart) for the form, "Manual Input" for input of the user? And "Process" for the process of filling in the form or for the process of the system of processing the data filled in?

Comment: However you want to! It's a work flow process diagram so may be break each bit down with "Get form", "Get pen or keyboard ready", conditional "If pen, remove lid", "Read question", "Think about the question as you don't want to get it wrong, especially if using pen" etc?! Or just have a process named "Print form", another called "fill the form numnuts!" etc. You may want to explain your question better

Comment: I supplemented my question

Answer (score 1):

My experience has been that if process diagrams will be presented to the leadership (which doesn't know all types of content type available in visio) we should just stick to basic flowchart where all actions can be depicted in a normal rectangle. Rather than forcing viewers to know the difference between manual input, document symbols - I decide to take that ownership and make it as user readable as possible.

I was hooked onto visio, then moved to omnigraffle and now I am in love with IBM - https://www.blueworkslive.com/#!gettingStarted:overview

If business process mapping is vital part of your work, I recommend going through above link to see how this tool might help.